# String to XML - OSB

Tags: xml, string, xquery, osb

I am trying to convert the contents of a file to a XML, which I can work on within my proxy. The problem is that I am using the inlinedXML function, which is supposed to return a structure that I can work on, using XPaths and XQueries, but instead I get ´|>, when I apply it on the XML structure below.

```
<SpecialChars>
  <ListOfChars>
    <Char>´</Char>
    <Char>|</Char>
  </ListOfChars>
</SpecialChars>
```

And when I try to use an XPath expression on it, I get the following errors:

```
`<`May 29, 2014 12:02:43 PM BRT> `<`Error> `<`OSB Kernel> `<`BEA-382004> `<`Failed to process request message for service ProxyService OSB/test: com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.expressions.xquery.XQueryExprExecutor.executeJavaObject(XQueryExprExecutor.java:138)
  at stages.logging.runtime.LogRuntimeStep.processMessage(LogRuntimeStep.java:123)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.debug.DebuggerRuntimeStep.processMessage(DebuggerRuntimeStep.java:74)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageMetadataImpl$WrapperRuntimeStep.processMessage(StageMetadataImpl.java:346)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.impl.SequenceRuntimeStep.processMessage(SequenceRuntimeStep.java:33)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.xml.query.exceptions.XQueryTypeException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.AbstractIterator.reportUserError(AbstractIterator.java:95)
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.AbstractIterator.reportUserError(AbstractIterator.java:134)
  at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.typing.SeqTypeMatching.fetchNext(SeqTypeMatching.java:189)
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.hasNext(GenericIterator.java:133)
  at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.navigation.ChildPath.fetchNext(ChildPath.java:159)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
`<`May 29, 2014 12:02:43 PM BRT> `<`Error> `<`OSB Kernel> `<`BEA-380003> `<`Exception on TransportManagerImpl.receiveMessage, com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.expressions.xquery.XQueryExprExecutor.executeJavaObject(XQueryExprExecutor.java:138)
  at stages.logging.runtime.LogRuntimeStep.processMessage(LogRuntimeStep.java:123)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.debug.DebuggerRuntimeStep.processMessage(DebuggerRuntimeStep.java:74)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageMetadataImpl$WrapperRuntimeStep.processMessage(StageMetadataImpl.java:346)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.impl.SequenceRuntimeStep.processMessage(SequenceRuntimeStep.java:33)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.xml.query.exceptions.XQueryTypeException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.AbstractIterator.reportUserError(AbstractIterator.java:95)
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.AbstractIterator.reportUserError(AbstractIterator.java:134)
  at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.typing.SeqTypeMatching.fetchNext(SeqTypeMatching.java:189)
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.hasNext(GenericIterator.java:133)
  at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.navigation.ChildPath.fetchNext(ChildPath.java:159)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
`<`May 29, 2014 12:02:43 PM BRT> `<`Warning> `<`EJB> `<`BEA-010065> `<`MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception was:
javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node.
javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.poller.listener.PolledMessageListenerMDB.__onMessage(PolledMessageListenerMDB.java:55)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.poller.listener.PolledMessageListenerMDB.access$000(PolledMessageListenerMDB.java:31)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.poller.listener.PolledMessageListenerMDB$1.run(PolledMessageListenerMDB.java:41)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.poller.listener.PolledMessageListenerMDB$1.run(PolledMessageListenerMDB.java:39)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
`<`May 29, 2014 12:02:43 PM BRT> `<`Warning> `<`EJB> `<`BEA-010065> `<`MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception was:
javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node.
javax.ejb.EJBException: nested exception is: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.poller.listener.PolledMessageListenerMDB.__onMessage(PolledMessageListenerMDB.java:55)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.poller.listener.PolledMessageListenerMDB.access$000(PolledMessageListenerMDB.java:31)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.poller.listener.PolledMessageListenerMDB$1.run(PolledMessageListenerMDB.java:41)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.poller.listener.PolledMessageListenerMDB$1.run(PolledMessageListenerMDB.java:39)
  at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
******************** START DUMP GlobalOperationsPOJO **********************
`<xml-fragment xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/domain/config"><con:monitoring>true</con:monitoring><con:reporting>true</con:reporting><con:logging>true</con:logging><con:sla-alerting>true</con:sla-alerting><con:pipeline-alerting>true</con:pipeline-alerting><con:result-caching>true</con:result-caching></xml-fragment>`
******************** END DUMP GlobalOperationsPOJO **********************
`<`May 29, 2014 12:02:43 PM BRT> `<`Error> `<`OSB Kernel> `<`BEA-382004> `<`Failed to process request message for service ProxyService OSB/test: com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.expressions.xquery.XQueryExprExecutor.executeJavaObject(XQueryExprExecutor.java:138)
  at stages.logging.runtime.LogRuntimeStep.processMessage(LogRuntimeStep.java:123)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.debug.DebuggerRuntimeStep.processMessage(DebuggerRuntimeStep.java:74)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageMetadataImpl$WrapperRuntimeStep.processMessage(StageMetadataImpl.java:346)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.impl.SequenceRuntimeStep.processMessage(SequenceRuntimeStep.java:33)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.xml.query.exceptions.XQueryTypeException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.AbstractIterator.reportUserError(AbstractIterator.java:95)
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.AbstractIterator.reportUserError(AbstractIterator.java:134)
  at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.typing.SeqTypeMatching.fetchNext(SeqTypeMatching.java:189)
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.hasNext(GenericIterator.java:133)
  at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.navigation.ChildPath.fetchNext(ChildPath.java:159)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
`<`May 29, 2014 12:02:43 PM BRT> `<`Error> `<`OSB Kernel> `<`BEA-380003> `<`Exception on TransportManagerImpl.receiveMessage, com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.expressions.xquery.XQueryExprExecutor.executeJavaObject(XQueryExprExecutor.java:138)
  at stages.logging.runtime.LogRuntimeStep.processMessage(LogRuntimeStep.java:123)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.pipeline.debug.DebuggerRuntimeStep.processMessage(DebuggerRuntimeStep.java:74)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.StageMetadataImpl$WrapperRuntimeStep.processMessage(StageMetadataImpl.java:346)
  at com.bea.wli.sb.stages.impl.SequenceRuntimeStep.processMessage(SequenceRuntimeStep.java:33)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.xml.query.exceptions.XQueryTypeException: line 1, column 7: {err}XP0006: "´| ({http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string)": bad value for type node
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.AbstractIterator.reportUserError(AbstractIterator.java:95)
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.AbstractIterator.reportUserError(AbstractIterator.java:134)
  at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.typing.SeqTypeMatching.fetchNext(SeqTypeMatching.java:189)
  at weblogic.xml.query.iterators.GenericIterator.hasNext(GenericIterator.java:133)
  at weblogic.xml.query.runtime.navigation.ChildPath.fetchNext(ChildPath.java:159)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am asking how to be able to work on a string, that has been converted into an XML, the same way I work on XMLs that are received as requests in my service. When I apply inlinedXML on the string, I cannot work on it as an XML, trying to print the XML, I can only see the content of the original string.

Comment: Where is the XML structure? And what xpath have you used?

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: I am asking how to be able to work on a string, that has been converted into an XML, the same way I work on XMLs that are received as requests in my service. When I apply inlinedXML on the string, I cannot work on it as an XML, trying to print the XML, I can only see the content of the original string.

Comment: You error message doesn't match your XML: the error message says "´|" while in XML those values are in different text nodes. Please show the exact XQuery you're using to parse this string into XML.

Comment: I understand that Vladimir, but that's exactly my issue. I don't understand why that's what I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: the variable you're trying to pass to inlinedXML() doesn't contain a string, but already has XML. In that case inlinedXML() *probably* tries to parse the *text nodes* available within the XML, causing it to try and parse symbols ' and | as XML, and fail (duh).

Try to do:

```
    count($var//*:SpecialChars)
```

If it gives you a number > 0, then you've already got XML, no need to parse.